# Как сделать чтобы во время тестов кастомный валидатор автовайрил репоизторий?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Использую валидатор для проверки уникальности номера. В валидаторе автовайрю репозиторий для поиска по БД. Валидатор работает, но при запуске тестов валидатор не хочет автовайрить репозиторий и тесты не проходит. Как победить эту беду?

Сама сущность:

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;

import javax.persistence.*;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "phone")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Phone implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "phone_number")
    private Integer phoneNumber;

    // jhipster-needle-entity-add-field - JHipster will add fields here, do not remove
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public Phone phoneNumber(Integer phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        return this;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(Integer phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }
    // jhipster-needle-entity-add-getters-setters - JHipster will add getters and setters here, do not remove

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Phone phone = (Phone) o;
        if (phone.getId() == null || getId() == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return Objects.equals(getId(), phone.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(getId());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Phone{" +
            "id=" + getId() +
            ", phoneNumber=" + getPhoneNumber() +
            "}";
    }
}
```

Валидатор:

```
import org.jhipster.blog.repository.PhoneRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

@Component
public class ContactNumberValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ContactNumberConstraint, Integer> {

    @Autowired
    private PhoneRepository repository;

    @Override
    public void initialize(ContactNumberConstraint phoneNumber) {
    }

    public ContactNumberValidator() {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Integer phoneNumber,
                           ConstraintValidatorContext cxt) {

        Phone result = repository.findFirstByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
        boolean b = result == null;
        return b;
    }
}
```

Контроллер в котором осуществляется валидация:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class PhoneResource {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PhoneResource.class);

    private static final String ENTITY_NAME = "phone";

    private final PhoneService phoneService;

    public PhoneResource(PhoneService phoneService) {
        this.phoneService = phoneService;
    }

    /**
     * POST  /phones : Create a new phone.
     *
     * @param phoneDTO the phoneDTO to create
     * @return the ResponseEntity with status 201 (Created) and with body the new phoneDTO, or with status 400 (Bad Request) if the phone has already an ID
     * @throws URISyntaxException if the Location URI syntax is incorrect
     */
    @PostMapping("/phones")
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<PhoneDTO> createPhone(@RequestBody @Valid PhoneDTO phoneDTO) throws URISyntaxException {
        log.debug("REST request to save Phone : {}", phoneDTO);
        if (phoneDTO.getId() != null) {
            throw new BadRequestAlertException("A new phone cannot already have an ID", ENTITY_NAME, "idexists");
        }
        PhoneDTO result = phoneService.save(phoneDTO);
        return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("/api/phones/" + result.getId()))
            .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityCreationAlert(ENTITY_NAME, result.getId().toString()))
            .body(result);
    }
...
}
```

Тест:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = BlogApp.class)
public class PhoneResourceIntTest {

    private static final Integer DEFAULT_PHONE_NUMBER = 1;
    private static final Integer UPDATED_PHONE_NUMBER = 2;

    @Autowired
    private PhoneRepository phoneRepository;


    @Autowired
    private PhoneMapper phoneMapper;


    @Autowired
    private PhoneService phoneService;

    @Autowired
    private MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonMessageConverter;

    @Autowired
    private PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver pageableArgumentResolver;

    @Autowired
    private ExceptionTranslator exceptionTranslator;

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager em;


    private MockMvc restPhoneMockMvc;

    private Phone phone;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        final PhoneResource phoneResource = new PhoneResource(phoneService);
        this.restPhoneMockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(phoneResource)
            .setCustomArgumentResolvers(pageableArgumentResolver)
            .setControllerAdvice(exceptionTranslator)
            .setConversionService(createFormattingConversionService())
            .setMessageConverters(jacksonMessageConverter).build();
    }

    /**
     * Create an entity for this test.
     *
     * This is a static method, as tests for other entities might also need it,
     * if they test an entity which requires the current entity.
     */
    public static Phone createEntity(EntityManager em) {
        Phone phone = new Phone()
            .phoneNumber(DEFAULT_PHONE_NUMBER);
        return phone;
    }

    @Before
    public void initTest() {
        phone = createEntity(em);
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void createPhone() throws Exception {
        int databaseSizeBeforeCreate = phoneRepository.findAll().size();

        // Create the Phone
        PhoneDTO phoneDTO = phoneMapper.toDto(phone);
        restPhoneMockMvc.perform(post("/api/phones")
            .contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(phoneDTO)))
            .andExpect(status().isCreated());

        // Validate the Phone in the database
        List<Phone> phoneList = phoneRepository.findAll();
        assertThat(phoneList).hasSize(databaseSizeBeforeCreate + 1);
        Phone testPhone = phoneList.get(phoneList.size() - 1);
        assertThat(testPhone.getPhoneNumber()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_PHONE_NUMBER);
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

С тестированием познакомился (в том числе и мокито) буквально на прошлой неделе, мне совсем не понятно для чего так тест "городить". Задача простая, проверить корректность метода `ContactNumberValidator` #isValid().

Что для этого нужно ?

Я вижу это так:

1. Нужен мок/спай `ContactNumberValidator`,
2. Чтобы при вызове `isValid()` метод правильно отработал нужен мок для `PhoneRepository`, с тем чтобы можно было сделать стаббинг для метода `findFirstByPhoneNumber`, который подсунет прямо в тесте же созданные объект - тут ничего не нужно вычитывать из базы..

Да, но чтобы иметь возможность использовать мок репозитория в тестовом методе (`isValid` имеется в виду) придется добавить геттер для репозитория в `ContactNumberValidator`, с помощью него можно будет сделать стаббинг геттера, который (репозиторий) будет создан в тесте в виде мока.

```
Phone result = getRepository().findFirstByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
```

Возможно, это некрасиво выглядит, но все выше описанное должно быть сведено к простой конструкции (это схема близка к тому что должно работать):

```
@Test
public void dummy() {
    ContactNumberValidator validator = spy(ContactNumberValidator.class);
    Integer phoneNumer = Integer.valueOf(12345);
    ConstraintValidatorContext ctx = new ConstraintValidatorContext();
    PhoneRepository repository = spy(PhoneRepository.class);
    Phone phone = new Phone();
    doReturn(repository).when(validator).getRepository();
    doReturn(phone).when(repository).findFirstByPhoneNumber(anyInt());

    bolean actual = validator.isValid(phoneNumer, ctx);
    Assert.assertFalse(actual);
}
```

Comment: Тесты сгененированы и мок-объекты в них испольовать  не получится. Я могу замокать нужные классы и написать мок-тест, но мне нужно чтобы работали раннее сгенерированные тесты.

Comment: поясните, что значит не получится использовать моки в тесте ? моки можно определять прямо в тест-методе и это никак не будет влиять на другие тестовые методы ?!

Comment: в SpringBootTest-ах мок-объекты не работают.

Comment: тут либо что-то вроде интеграционного тестирования, когда тест имитирует реальную работу (некоторой части приложения) - то есть все объекты действительно создаются, либо это тестирование с моками каждого класса по отдельности.. то есть Ваш выбор это первое ?

Comment: Это не то чтобы мой выбор - так было сгенерировано приложение и интеграционные тесты должны продолжать работать

Comment: возвращаясь к сути вопроса, чтобы `PhoneRepository` инициализировался, где-то должна быть конфигурация, в которой явно создается этот бин, то есть имеет метод  `@Bean PhoneRepository reposotiry(){...}`, и соответственно, `ContactNumberValidator` должен о ней знать.. тут я точно не знаю, будет ли работать `@Autowired` для репозитория если класс с этим методом (до)-прописать в сlasses `@SpringBootTest` тестового класса